# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'pictures.-LdqDWmOg30CiBelxyfR.image'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have problems with firebase image upload. 
Code issue:

```
const record = {
                      photoURL: this.state.user.photoURL,
                      displayName: this.state.user.displayName,
                      image: task.snapshot.downloadURL
                    };
      const dbRef = firebase.database().ref('pictures');
      const newPicture = dbRef.push();
      newPicture.set(record);
    });
```

I think this problem is because I set an object to pictures child.